# Boot loader not working, Grub Rescue Mode is showing instead

Tags: kali-linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

i used to have kali linux with my windows 10 on dual boot mode hosted by kali grub bootloader. Both OS had their seperate memory in partition. Recently i went to my windows OS and removed/cleared the kali partition and used and allocated that free space to my windows. Then i restarted my computer ans this following message was shown. I'm now not able to access my windows.I have a lot of important memory in my harddrive. My friend told me that i didn't switch the bootloader from kali before removing it is what caused the best problem. I don't exactly know. How can now i access my windows and repair my bootloader
This is what it is showing now :-
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode ...
grub rescue>

Comment: Well the good news is that your files are not lost, you just can't boot.  Think carefully about what you want to do.  This site is for linux, so if you want to fix linux we can help.  If you want to fix windows then maybe try https://superuser.com/ .Either way could you edit your question to show which direction you would prefer.

Comment: @P_Yadav that isn't helpful and it's not appropriate.  Please don't treat new users this way/

Answer (score -1):

Burn a Windows installation disk and use the recovery/fix utilities.